# Show that the composition of an operator and its inverse is commutative.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am posed with the following problem:

> Suppose that $V$ is finite-dimensional and that $S,T\in \mathcal{L}(V)$. Prove that $ST=I$ if and only if $TS=I$, where $I$ is the identity map/operator.

I have attempted it in the following way.

Consider the proof in one direction, starting at the equality $ST=I$. If we multiply by $S$ on both sides (which means take the composition of $S$ on both sides), we get

$$(ST)S=IS=S$$

However, the composition of operators is associative, so

$$(ST)S=S(TS)$$

Which means we have, from what we just got in the last two equalities,

$$S(TS)=S$$

And since this should work for all $v\in V$, this means that $TS=I$. Thus, $ST=I \implies TS=I$.

For the proof in the other direction, just replace every $S$ with a $T$ and vice versa. $\blacksquare$.

---

Is this proof valid? Is there a shorter or easier proof? Please be very holistic.

Comment: Your simplification is valid if you prove $S$ is injective.

Comment: Why would it become valid if I were to prove $S$ is injective?

Comment: It's a general fact about sets and maps, not vector spaces: if $SU=SV$, and if $S$ is injective, then $U=V$. Similarly, if $UT=TV$  and if $T$ is surjective, then $U=V$.

Comment: After reading this comment, a bit more from my textbook, and thinking, I can see why this is true. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help... Btw, another general fact I used in my comment: if $f\circ g$ is injective, $g$ is injective. If s surjective, $f$ is surjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $ST=I$, you deduce that $S$ is surjective and $T$ injective (this point has nothing to do with vector spaces).
Now for a linear map $f\colon E \rightarrow F$ between vector spaces `of the same (finite) dimension`, the following are equivalent:

1. $f$ is injective;
2. $f$ is surjective;
3. $f$ is bijective.

(This results from the `rank theorem`).
Hence $S$ and $T$ are isomorphisms, which are reciprocal of each other. As a consequence, of course, $ST=TS=I$.

Answer (score 1):

Your purported proof does not use that $V$ is finite dimensional. This is an *essential* part of the argument because the result is false otherwise.

Consider $V = c_c$, the set of sequences of real numbers which are eventually zero and the left and right shift operators

$S(x_1,x_2,\dotsc) = (x_2,\dotsc)$.
$T(x_1,x_2,\dotsc) = (0,x_1,x_2,\dotsc)$.

Then we have that $ST = I$, but $TS(x_1,x_2,\dotsc) = (0,x_2,\dotsc)$.

Comment: Ah, I see. What if I were to explicitly say that $V$ is finite-dimensional?